# What is used to code this site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, scriptaculous

the website sym baloo .com has the ability to move icons about the screen. You can drag and drop the little tiles from one square to another. Also this must be able to update the database with the new position of the tile.

Can anyone tell me what's the best way to achieve this, either the way they've done it or anyother way.

Comment: [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) & [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) probably,

Comment: take a look at their source code; read the Javascript includes; See what the JS file names are; Research those filenames; answer your own question.

Comment: Use the source, Luke. You'll find the site is using MooTools, most likely extended with a bunch of plugins and glue code.

Answer (score 2):

The web in question uses [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) and possibly an extension for it to achieve the drag+drop effect. Check out [their builder site](http://mootools.net/more/) to build the functionality you'll need for your website.

As for database updating, it's not a question of what they use. You will need to devise your own database schema and backend for it (PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby...).

Answer (score 0):

```
-- id = Id of content what u drag--
    $("#id").draggable({
        revert: true
    });
-- id= Id of content where u drop--
        $("#id").droppable();

        $("#id").droppable({
            tolerance: 'touch',
            over: function () {
                $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#cedae3');
            },
            out: function () {
                $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#a6bcce');
            },
}
);
```

Comment: the answer you posted initially was 3 lines, copy+paste of a jq-ui drag-drop code without any explanation, and was not even working - that was not an answer and that's why I downvoted you

Comment: ohh friend it was posted bymistake that time.. but now i edited it.. cant u wait littel momment?...

Comment: sorry, I can't retract my vote now, but you could've deleted and re-posted your answer later if you mistakenly submitted it in the first place

Comment: ok fine.. now we cant do anything...